# Is there a way to get a list of VS 2005 project files into text or xml format?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, file

Does anyone know how or where I can go to quickly extract a list of all of my project files from VS 2005?  I need to bring the file names into Excel/Access/SharePoint for Project Management duties (i.e. update logs, etc.), so XML or some other text/delimited text format would be ideal.

I want to get the actual file names (i.e. Default1.aspx, Default1.aspx.vb, Default2.aspx, Default2.aspx.vb, UserControl.ascx, UserControl.ascx.vb) into a list format. I don't necessarily want just a count of files. I need the full list.

Comment: What do you mean? Count a number of files into specific project? Or count a number of project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/download.htm)

1. Navigate to a folder
2. Menu > Commands > Search and hit enter
3. Press 'Feed to listbox' button
4. Select all files in pane
5. Menu > Mark > Copy Names With Path to Clipboard and paste in Excel
6. Sort the names in Excel

You can also use the filter in the search dialog to exclude some extensions.